# Relevant operators in Ising model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, ising-model

Why in 3d Ising near critical point there are only **two relevant deformations**?

I am interested in experimental arguments and also in theoretical explanation.

For example, in [3D Ising Model and Conformal Bootstrap](https://indico.cern.ch/event/183290/contributions/318659/attachments/249595/349051/Rychkov1.pdf) there is list of operators:

[image]

**How to prove that there are only two such operators? How to check this experimentally for some model in $Ising_3$ universality class?**

Comment: Are you asking for a more physical explanation than the statement that the 3d Ising CFT has two primary operators (the weights of which correspond to the critical exponents)?

Comment: Physically, I think it's generally true that the number of relevant scalars at the critical point is in one-to-one correspondence to the number of directions on a phase diagram. As water and ferromagnets are in the Ising universality class, and their phases diagrams are two-dimensional (temperature and pressure for water; temperature and magnetic field for magnets) assuming two relevant directions is physically well-motivated.

Comment: @4xion, so you statement is true for any system with 2d phase diagram? Itbis strange